# How to get image Exif data using OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

Does OpenCV support getting Exif data of images? Is there a program in OpenCV that parses the Exif data and get appropriate fields?

Answer (score 8):

As of 3.1 opencv `imread` handles exif orientation perfectly. I know this is an old question, but I struggled to find an answer to this same question recently, so am posting here. Apparently `cvLoadImage` does not handle exif orientation correctly at this time according to a [bug report](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6673) on github.

You can find a nice set of sample images with different exif rotations and a good explanation [here](http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2012/07/28/exif-orientation-handling-is-a-ghetto/)

Comment: So can I get EXIF metadata using opencv's `imread`? I am looking at the docs [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) but it seems it can only *take into account* the orientation, rather than returning a dict with the exif tags...

Answer (score -3):

OpenCV has no Exif support. It's not the purpose of OpenCV.